# FloatingPointError in calculating standard deviation?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Using `pandas/numpy`, I sometimes get the floating point error when trying to calculate a standard deviation:

> FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in less

My code looks something like this:

```
def historical_volatility(p):
    return p.pct_change().ewm(span=35, min_periods=35).std()
```

It is only DataFrames of floats going in.

My understanding is that for a technical reason related to how the standard deviation is calculated computationally, situations with particularly low deviation will result in a floating point error.

How can I make this more robust?

P.S. It is acceptable to set a 'minimum value' for low volatility; a result of 0 would be bad as I am subsequently dividing by these numbers.

Comment: can you provide a sample that reproduces this error?

Comment: I don't know pandas/numpy, but can you use decimal instead of float?  Its slower, but can be more accurate as a trade-off

Answer (score 0):

Computing standard deviation likely involves doing a square root of the variance. The latter can only be negative if there's some precision loss. If this is the case, you likely don't care if your variance is of the order of 1e-16 or zero. If you do, you likely need to use extended precision (not easy), or switch to decimal arithmetics.